# Compiling multiple datatables with Vue.js completely from JSON data using single template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dynamic

I am looking to create a single vue template to generate 40+ `datatables` where I will pass in different table definitions via an API.

I am struggling to dynamic pull in the table data using key names in my table definition.

I have tried to bind the text using `{{` and `v-text` but i got the same error

**JS**

```
data() {
     return {
         tableColumns: [
          {
            columnName : "First Name",
            columnValue : "first_name",
            visible : true,
            align: "left"
             },
             {
              columnName : "Last Name",
              columnValue: "last_name",
              visible : true,
              align: "left"
              }],
             people : [],
           };
        }
```

**Blade**

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-for="(tableColumn, index) in tableColumns" :key="index">
          @{{ tableColumn.columnName}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(person, index) in people.data" :key="index">
          <td v-for="(tableColumn, indexColumn) in tableColumns" :key="indexColumn" >
            <p v-text="person.[tableColumn.columnValue]"></p>
          </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
```

**ERROR:**

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token [ in

    person.[tableColumn.columnValue]

  Raw expression: v-text="person.[tableColumn.columnValue]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help people who might stumble across this in future, the problem was where I was building my vue component. Instead of having the component logic in my component.blade.php I made a standalone .vue file and that did the trick.

Final working version:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-for="(tableColumn, index) in tableColumns" :key="index">
          {{ tableColumn.columnName}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in rows.data">
            <td v-for="tableColumn in tableColumns" >
              {{row[tableColumn.columnValue]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```